# Bluetooth not working on Zoostorm laptop

Tags: bluetooth, realtek

Trying to get my laptop to connect with my Samsung S3 and/or an A2DP receiver over bluetooth.  The S3 can see the laptop (but pairing just times out).  The laptop usually* cannot see anything - the bluetooth scan just seems to run forever.  (*Once it showed what I presume to be a neighbour's Nokia! I can't reproduce this but I'm sure it happened.)

sudo rfkill list all :

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I don't know what Bluetooth device it has - don't recognise it from the following lists:

sudo lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

sudo lsusb :

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b002 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0eef:a130 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd    
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0247 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have tried (from various answers on here) with no discernible effect:

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth blueman bluez-hcidump bluewho python-bluez  bluez-tools brcm-patchram-plus-nexus7

sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups   bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez   bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms rtl8723au-bt-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't appear to make any difference.